# Where to initialize SSE constants

Tags: c++, constants, sse, simd

My question is about the most efficient place to define `__m128`/`__m128i` compile time constants in intrinsics based code.

Considering two options:

### Option A

```
__m128i Foo::DoMasking(const __m128i value) const
{
    //defined in method
    const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x00FF0000);
    return _mm_and_si128(value, mask);
}
```

### Option B

```
//Foo.h
const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x00FF0000);

//Foo.cpp
__m128i Foo::DoMasking(const __m128i value) const
{
    return _mm_and_si128(value, mask);
}
```

- Will option A incur a performance penalty, or will it be optimized away to an equivalent of option B?
- Is there a better yet *option C*?
- does the answer change depending on whether or not the method is inlined?
- Is `_mm_set1_epi32`/`__mm_set_epi32` the best way to load the constants? I've seen some questions in which an `int[4]` is generated and cast to an `__m128i`.

I know the appropriate answer to all of these questions is *"check the disassembly!"*, but I'm inexperienced in both generating it and interpreting it.

I am compiling on MSVC with maximum optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option A will *probably* be OK - the compiler *should* do the right thing when it inlines this function and it should hoist the mask constant out of any loops, but the safest option in my experience, particularly if you want this to work reliably across multiple platforms/compilers, is to re-factor this into a slightly less elegant but potentially more efficient form:

```
__m128i Foo::DoMasking(const __m128i value, const __m128i mask) const
{
    return _mm_and_si128(value, mask);
}

void Foo::DoLotsOfMasking(...)
{
    const __m128i mask = _mm_set1_epi32(0x00FF0000);

    for (int i = 0; ...; ...)
    {
        // ...
        v[i] = DoMasking(x[i], mask);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was hoping you'd answer this question :) Portability is not a concern in this case. If I understand you correctly, it is more efficient (or *as* efficient) to pass the constant to the function than to initialize it in the header or class?

Comment: Well, there are no guarantees with this sort of thing, and different versions of the same compiler, or different compiler options, may result in different behaviour. I think either Option A or B should be OK, although I would prefer A, but my alternative is probably a safer bet, since the constant will typically be generated once, before the loop, and kept in a register. As always, profile your code!

Comment: How do you handle SIMD Constant in `C`? While in `C++` one could do `static __m128  const a = _mm_set1_ps(12102203.2f);` and use `a` in the code, what should one do in `C`?

Comment: @PaulR, I tried explaining myself better at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139380.