# Define a `static const` SIMD Variable within a `C` Function

Tags: c, optimization, vectorization, sse, simd

I have a function in this form (From [Fastest Implementation of Exponential Function Using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025373)):

```
__m128 FastExpSse(__m128 x)
{
    static __m128  const a   = _mm_set1_ps(12102203.2f); // (1 << 23) / ln(2)
    static __m128i const b   = _mm_set1_epi32(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);
    static __m128  const m87 = _mm_set1_ps(-87);
    // fast exponential function, x should be in [-87, 87]
    __m128 mask = _mm_cmpge_ps(x, m87);

    __m128i tmp = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_mul_ps(a, x)), b);
    return _mm_and_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(tmp), mask);
}
```

I want to make it `C` compatible.
Yet the compiler doesn't accept the form `static __m128i const b   = _mm_set1_epi32(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);` when I use `C` compiler.

Yet I don't want the first 3 values to be recalculated in each function call.
One solution is to inline it (But sometimes the compilers reject that).

Is there a `C` style to achieve it in case the function isn't inlined?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `static` and `const`.

Also remove them from the C++ version. `const` is OK, but `static` is horrible, introducing guard variables that are checked every time, and a very expensive initialization the first time.

`__m128 a = _mm_set1_ps(12102203.2f);` is not a function call, it's just a way to express a vector constant. No time can be saved by "doing it only once" - it normally happens *zero* times, with the constant vector being prepared in the data segment of the program and simply being loaded at runtime, without the junk around it that `static` introduces.

Check the asm to be sure, without `static` this is what happens: ([from godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZIrmOz))

```
FastExpSse(float __vector(4)):
        movaps  xmm1, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        cmpleps xmm1, xmm0
        mulps   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        cvtps2dq        xmm0, xmm0
        paddd   xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC2[rip]
        andps   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   3266183168
        .long   3266183168
        .long   3266183168
        .long   3266183168
.LC1:
        .long   1262004795
        .long   1262004795
        .long   1262004795
        .long   1262004795
.LC2:
        .long   1064866805
        .long   1064866805
        .long   1064866805
        .long   1064866805
```

Comment: Are you sure that you do not confuse with the __thread keyword ? Static and const should not add any more code. It should produce the same code that you shown

Comment: Oh, I see, this is because you build the code with a C++ compiler, I was talking about C code. And you are right, in C++ code adding static add "complex code"

Comment: @benjarobin well that part was about C++. For C, marking the vector constants static is not even possible.

Comment: @harold, You say that removing both in `C` will yield a code with zero overhead for that part? Is there a reason why the people answered the linked question used it? +1.

Comment: @Royi yes, no real overhead. Though if inlined, the loads of the constants may be put before a loop, that sort of thing. Anyway I don't see any static variables in the linked answers so IDK

Comment: @benjarobin: `static const` *shouldn't* add anything, but unlike `static const int table[4] = {1,2,3,4};`, compilers suck and somehow fail to optimize away `_mm_set` intrinsics with compile-time-constant values.  Harold is right: let the compiler handle vector constants the same way it handles string literals like when you write `char *foo = "hello";`, by possibly deduplicating across functions and whatnot.

Comment: Let's say it was inlined, is there anything to do to optimize it? For instance, as you said, if it inside a loop not to make the same operation over and over.

Comment: @Royi: Compilers know how to hoist constant-setup out of loops after inlining, even MSVC these days.

Comment: @Royi: "*why the people answered the linked question used it?*" I don't see any use of `static` variables in [Fastest Implementation of Exponential Function Using SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47025373), only `const` (which is just a compile time restriction on what the function can do, and doesn't mean anything as far as where it's stored.)

Comment: @PeterCordes  I was agreed with harold's answer and I learned a bit from him (thank you), sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 4):

`_mm_set1_ps(-87);` or any other `_mm_set` intrinsic is not a valid static initializer with current compilers, because it's not treated as a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression).

In C++, it compiles to runtime initialization of the `static` storage location (copying from a vector literal somewhere else).  And if it's a `static __m128` inside a function, there's a guard variable to protect it.

In C, it simply refuses to compile, because C doesn't support non-constant initializers / constructors.  `_mm_set` is not like a braced initializer for the underlying GNU C native vector, like @benjarobin's answer shows.

---

This is really dumb, and seems to be a missed-optimization in all 4 mainstream x86 C++ compilers (gcc/clang/ICC/MSVC).  Even if it somehow matters that each `static const __m128 var` have a distinct address, the compiler could achieve that by using initialized read-only storage instead of copying at runtime.

So it seems like constant propagation fails to go all the way to turning `_mm_set` into a constant initializer even when optimization is enabled.

---

#### Never use `static const __m128 var = _mm_set...` even in C++; it's inefficient.

Inside a function is even worse, but global scope is still bad.

Instead, avoid `static`.  You can still use `const` to stop yourself from accidentally assigning something else, and to tell human readers that it's a constant.  Without `static`, it has no effect on where/how your variable is stored.  `const` on automatic storage just does compile-time checking that you don't modify the object.

```
const __m128 var = _mm_set1_ps(-87);    // not static
```

**Compilers are good at this, and *will* optimize the case where multiple functions use the same vector constant, the same way they de-duplicate string literals and put them in read-only memory.**

Defining constants this way inside small helper functions is fine: compilers will hoist the constant-setup out of a loop after inlining the function.

It also lets compilers optimize away the full 16 bytes of storage, and load it with `vbroadcastss xmm0, dword [mem]`, or stuff like that.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is clearly **not** portable, it's working with GCC 8 (only tested with this compiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_M128(vFloat)  {(vFloat), (vFloat), (vFloat), (vFloat)}
#define INIT_M128I(vU32)   {((uint64_t)(vU32) | (uint64_t)(vU32) << 32u), ((uint64_t)(vU32) | (uint64_t)(vU32) << 32u)}

static void print128(const void *p)
{
    unsigned char buf[16];

    memcpy(buf, p, 16);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
    {
        printf("%02X ", buf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    static __m128  const glob_a = INIT_M128(12102203.2f);
    static __m128i const glob_b = INIT_M128I(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);
    static __m128  const glob_m87 = INIT_M128(-87.0f);

    __m128  a   = _mm_set1_ps(12102203.2f); 
    __m128i b   = _mm_set1_epi32(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);
    __m128  m87 = _mm_set1_ps(-87);

    print128(&a);
    print128(&glob_a);

    print128(&b);
    print128(&glob_b);

    print128(&m87);
    print128(&glob_m87);

    return 0;
}
```

As explained in the answer of @harold (in C only), the following code (build with or without `WITHSTATIC`) produces exactly the same code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INIT_M128(vFloat)  {(vFloat), (vFloat), (vFloat), (vFloat)}
#define INIT_M128I(vU32)   {((uint64_t)(vU32) | (uint64_t)(vU32) << 32u), ((uint64_t)(vU32) | (uint64_t)(vU32) << 32u)}

__m128 FastExpSse2(__m128 x)
{
#ifdef WITHSTATIC
    static __m128  const a = INIT_M128(12102203.2f);
    static __m128i const b = INIT_M128I(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);
    static __m128  const m87 = INIT_M128(-87.0f);
#else
    __m128  a   = _mm_set1_ps(12102203.2f);
    __m128i b   = _mm_set1_epi32(127 * (1 << 23) - 486411);
    __m128  m87 = _mm_set1_ps(-87);
#endif

    __m128 mask = _mm_cmpge_ps(x, m87);

    __m128i tmp = _mm_add_epi32(_mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_mul_ps(a, x)), b);
    return _mm_and_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(tmp), mask);
}
```

So in summary it's better to remove **static** and **const** keywords (better and simpler code in C++, and in C the code is portable since with my proposed hack the code is not really portable)